# Fiddler. Замена в URL запроса

Tags: url

Здравствуйте, профи!

Есть список ссылок вида http://www.example.com/XXXXX , где XXXXX для каждой ссылки разные.

Когда в броузере открывается такая ссылка, то данные подгружаются скриптом с URL вида 
*example.com/bbb/ccc/0-0-XXXXX-10-500-YYYYY.dat?_=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ* ,
где XXXXX, как уже упоминалось - разные ля каждой ссылки. А также разные YYYYY и ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ (генерируются скриптом)

Можно ли настроить Fiddler таким образом, что при открытии ссылки
example.com/XXXXX 
и подгрузки данных с URL 
*example.com/bbb/ccc/0-0-XXXXX-**10**-500-YYYYY.dat?_=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ* 
он автоматически посылал запрос на URL
*example.com/bbb/ccc/0-0-XXXXX-**20**-500-YYYYY.dat?_=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ* ?

Т.е. что бы в URL запроса заменялось 10-500 на 20-500.

Answer (score 1):

В OnBeforeRequest() можно написать условие вида:

```
if (oSession.uriContains("XXXXX-10-500")) {
    oSession.url = oSession.url.ToString().Replace("XXXXX-10-500", "XXXXX-20-500");
}
```